# JavaFX with or without Rich Client Platform

Tags: javafx

I'm starting to delve into JavaFX and have heard that one of the cons of java fx is that there isn't a mature rich client platform or application framework ala eclipse rcp or netbeats platform for it.

Why does JavaFX need a rich client platform? Do these things offer something that pure java fx does not offer on it's own? Does this lack of an application framework mean that JavaFX is not suited for huge enterprise applications that require plugins and stuff like that?

Answer (score 1):

Not having an RCP framework does NOT mean JavaFX is not suited for big applications, but requires you to invent more things yourself. Anyways there are RCP frameworks for JavaFX. One is built on top of Eclipse4 and it provides everything you expect from such a thing, it inherits the plugin/module concept and service modell from OSGi, adds a DI container, command and docking framework.

You can find more about it at http://efxclipse.org

Others i know of are afterburner.fx, griffon.fx and jacp.fx